# Why are Pages/Numbers/Keynote not free in the App Store on new iPhone 6s?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, iwork

I got a new iPhone in the US, but am using it abroad (Israel) and with my old Apple ID.

In the App Store I see the Apple Pages/Numbers/Keynote with a price tag on them (not free) when they should be free.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After taking it up with Apple Support, here is the answer:
The **first user** (AppleID) which activates a new iPhone gets those apps free. If the iPhone is reset to defaults and another user (AppleID) is used, which is what I did, then that user does **not** get them for free.

So the free option is a one time thing.

Comment: My guess would be that they're trying to avoid people just resetting a device over and over and getting the free apps on their Apple ID when the goal is to have it be a bonus for new hardware purchases.